# SSIS / SQL Server - dealing with various money type notations

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, type-conversion

In a SQL Server money column how can I deal with different currency notations coming in from country specific Excel files via SSIS (in varchar - transformed to money), taking care of comma and dot representation to make sure the values stay correct?

For example if these are three column values in Excel:

**22,333.44**

**22.333,44**

**22333,44**

the first notation above will result in 22,3334, which of course is incorrect.

What do I need to do with the data? Is it a string replace or something more elegant?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:**
After discussion in comments the problem has been clarified. The values in the excel column can be of many different regional formats (English using commas to separate thousands and '.' for decimal point, German using '.' for separating thousands and comma for decimal point).

Assuming that the destination format is English and you don't have an accompanying column to indicate the format then you're gonna have to implement a kludge of a workaround. If you can guarantee there will always be 2 numbers after the "decimal place" (comma in german format) then REPLACE(REPLACE(@Value,',',''),'.','') will get rid of every comma/point. Then you will have to get the length of the resulting varchar and manually insert a decimal (or comma) before the last 2 characters. Here's a sample implementation:

```
declare @number varchar(12),@trimmednumber varchar(12),@inserteddecimal varchar(12)
set @number='22.333,44'
select @trimmednumber=REPLACE(REPLACE(@number,',',''),'.','')
select @inserteddecimal=(LEFT(@trimmednumber,len(@trimmednumber)-2) + '.' + RIGHT(@trimmednumber,2))
select @number AS [Original],@trimmednumber AS [Trimmed],@inserteddecimal AS [Result]
```

And the results:

```
Original     Trimmed      Result
------------ ------------ ------------
22.333,44    2233344      22333.44
```

**Original Answer:**

I may be misunderstanding your question but if you take in those values as VARCHAR and insert them into MONEY columns then the implicit conversion should be correct.

Here's what I've knocked together to test:

```
declare @money_varchar1 varchar(12),@money_varchar2 varchar(12),@money_varchar3 varchar(12)
set @money_varchar1='22,333.44'
set @money_varchar2='22.333,44'
set @money_varchar3='22333,22'
declare @table table (Value money)
insert into @table values (@money_varchar1)
insert into @table values (@money_varchar2)
insert into @table values (@money_varchar3)
select * from @table
```

And the results:

```
Value
---------------------
22333.44
22.3334
2233322.00
```

Comment: ok, you are misunderstanding my question or I am  misunderstanding your example :-) I mean the values in your example are all different when in reality the numbers are the same (twenty-two thousand) value-wise and shouldn't be interpreted as twenty-two dollars (that's how I read the second output line) for example.

Comment: The values you provided are all different. When you say they are the same (22,000), where/how are they the same? The 3 excel values you provided are all different values. If you are saying that you need to ignore any commas or decimal points then you can use REPLACE(@Value,',','') to manually remove them, and then insert the result with all these removed into you database. But I'm curious why the commas and decimals would be there in the first place if you are going to ignore them?

Comment: they are the same because of different formatting / notation standards. Have a look at this:

** US Format - 1,234,567.89**
** German Format - 1.234.567,89**

same value but different delimiters.

Comment: Now I get ya. You'll need to define a standard format and adhere to it. With differing format types in the same column, if you don't have an associated column detailing the format the value is in then you're gonna have to implement a kludge of a workaround. I'll update the answer above with one way of doing it.

Comment: Probably the better solution will be if your function find the last comma or dot and this character be decimal seperator, not the last two characters...